# Primefaces slectOneMenu uses itemLabel as itemValue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an `<p:selectOneMenu>` which has an `<f:selectItems>` and in this `<f:selectItems>` I have set an `itemLabel` and an `itemValue`. The Item Value is an `Enum` Object which contains only a String and the Label is these String. The value of the `<p:selectOneMenu>` is an Collection of these `Enum` Objects. The selectOneMenu has an `valueChangeListener` and when its called it becomes the label as "new Value" and not the value. Has anyone an idea how I can fix this?

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="changeSpracheMenu"
                     value="#{sessionManager.currentUser.sprache}"
                     label="#{messageManager.getMessage('USER')}"
                     valueChangeListener="#{sessionManager.updateSpracheForCurrenUser}"
                     converter="sprachConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messageManager.getMessage('LANGUAGE')}"
                      noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{sprachManager.allSprachen}" var="sprache"
                       itemLabel="#{messageManager.getMessage('LANGUAGE_'.concat(sprache.name))}"
                       itemValue="#{sprache}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="@form"  />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Event of valueChangeListener, you can send the value of your selectItem to your bean.

For that, you have to modify

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="@form"  />
```

To:

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{yourBean.yourMethod(sprache)}" update="@form"  />
```

Now in your bean:

```
private yourObject sprache;
//getter/setter

public void yourMethod(yourObject typeSprache){
    whatever xyz = typeSprache.getWhatEverYouWant();
}
```

Comment: I have changed it like you said, but it won't work. The converter becomes the Label as Value. Only if i remove the Label he becomes the Value. And in the Metod from the listener is the given Parameter only null.

Comment: I have debugged the converter he becomes for the getAsObject Method as Value the Text from the ItemLabel and not the ItemValue. As example if my itemLabel is "Hello World" and the ItemValue is "EN" then the Converter becomes "Hello World" as Value. If i remove the ItemLabel from the <f:selectItems> it works and he becomes the EN.

Comment: Well, you just have to adjust your converter then!

Comment: What should i adjust in my converter? Where could be Problem?